# UIGestureRecognizerDelegate implemenation doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I've tried to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in my ViewController and somehow the methods aren't called. This is the controller:

```
#import "DiaryEntryViewController.h"
#import "UINavigationController+BarManagement.h"

@interface DiaryEntryViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation DiaryEntryViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)inAnimated{
    [super viewWillAppear:inAnimated];
    self.navigationController.barsHidden = NO;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)inAnimated{
    [super viewDidAppear:inAnimated];
    [self.navigationController hideBarsWithDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)inAnimated{
    [self.navigationController setBarsHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:inAnimated];
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return self.diaryEntry.managedObjectContext;
}

-(BOOL)saveDiaryEntry{
    BOOL theResult = NO;
    NSError *theError = nil;

    theResult = [self.managedObjectContext save:&theError];
    if(!theResult){
        NSLog(@"saveItem %@", theError);
    }

    return theResult;
}

-(CGRect)visibleBounds{
    CGRect theBounds = self.view.bounds;

    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)] && [self respondsToSelector:@selector(bottomLayoutGuide)]){
        theBounds.origin.y = [self.topLayoutGuide length];
        theBounds.size.height -= [self.topLayoutGuide length] + [self.bottomLayoutGuide length];
    }
    return theBounds;
}

-(IBAction)toogleBars:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"toogleBars");
    UINavigationController *theController = self.navigationController;
    BOOL theHiddenFlag = theController.barsHidden;

    [theController setBarsHidden:!theHiddenFlag animated:YES];
    if(theHiddenFlag){
        [theController hideBarsWithDelay:2.0];
    }

}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)inRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizerShouldBegin");
    UIView *theView = self.textView;
    CGPoint thePoint = [inRecognizer locationInView:theView];

    return !CGRectContainsPoint(theView.bounds, thePoint);
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"bla");

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"ble");
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"blä");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

It does call toogleBars methods, but none of the recognizer methods.

Comment: You have not declared any instance of UIGestureRecognier, adding only the delegate is not enough

Comment: I take it you added the UIGestureRecognizer directly via the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have added the `UIGestureRecognizer` from the storyboard, you need to remember to **CTRL + Drag** the gesture object to the `UIViewController` yellow circle image and set the delegate.

Your `UIGestureRecognizer` object will be on the top of the `UIViewController` view. CTL Drag this to the yellow circle ViewController icon

[image]

Then this pop-up will show and select 'Delegate' so that the gesutureRecognizer will use the delegate methods.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to declare and add the recognizer to the view you want to detect that tap or swipe in

example:

Add a property like "theTapRecognizer" to the VC.

Alloc and init that recognizer:

```
self.theTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(someMethod:)];
self.theTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[someView addGestureRecognizer: selftheTapRecognizer];
```

someView is the placeholder text to the view you want to init that recognizer in, it can be the whole self.view or some subview, 
you can listen for any interaction with that gesture recognizer with the following delegate method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```